# aggregate over several variables in r

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have a rather large dataset in a long format where I need to count the number of instances of the ID due to two different variables, A & B. E.g. The same person can be represented in multiple rows due to either A or B. What I need to do is to count the number of instances of ID which is not too hard, but also count the number of ID due to A and B and return these as variables in the dataset.

Regards,

//Mi

Comment: Please put up some representative rows of a hypothetical dataset and specific result you want out of those rows.  The question is wildly open to multiple interpretations.

Comment: As John said, put a sample data, so we can play around with it. I still don't get the message well, but `which` can be a function of choice, I presume...

Answer (score 3):

The `ddply()` function from the package `plyr` lets you break data apart by identifier variables, perform a function on each chunk, and then assemble it all back together.  So you need to break your data apart by identifier and A/B status, count how many times each of those combinations occur (using `nrow()`), and then put those counts back together nicely.

Using wkmor1's `df`:

```
library(plyr)

x <- ddply(.data = df, .var = c("ID", "GRP"), .fun = nrow)
```

which returns:

```
  ID GRP V1
1  1   a  2
2  1   b  2
3  2   a  2
4  2   b  2
```

And then merge that back on to the original data:

```
merge(x, df, by = c("ID", "GRP"))
```

Comment: ... if you're going to downvote, could you at least mention why?

Answer (score 3):

OK, given the interpretations I see, then the fastest and easiest solution is...

```
df$IDCount <- ave(df$ID, df$group, FUN = length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using 'table' to count rows meeting your criteria, and 'merge' to add the frequencies back to the data frame.

```
> df<-data.frame(ID=rep(c(1,2),4),GRP=rep(c("a","a","b","b"),2))
> id.frq <- as.data.frame(table(df$ID))
> colnames(id.frq) <- c('ID','ID.FREQ')
> df <- merge(df,id.frq)
> grp.frq <- as.data.frame(table(df$ID,df$GRP))
> colnames(grp.frq) <- c('ID','GRP','GRP.FREQ')
> df <- merge(df,grp.frq)
> df
  ID GRP ID.FREQ GRP.FREQ
1  1   a       4        2
2  1   a       4        2
3  1   b       4        2
4  1   b       4        2
5  2   a       4        2
6  2   a       4        2
7  2   b       4        2
8  2   b       4        2
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what was meant by 'return these as variables in the dataset', but I interpreted it as best I could.

Comment: ... yeah, I didn't have a clue about that until I saw yours.